# Java Warnings for fields in Domino / XPages

Tags: java, xpages

I have in my xpages numerous warnings like these:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type safety: The expression of type Vector needs unchecked conversion to conform to List    CustomerDominoDAO.java  /db.nsf/WebContent/WEB-INF/src/se/acme/customer/dao line 198    Java Problem

```
mailList.setPhones(doc.getItemValue("phones"));
```

where

```
private List<String> phones =new List<String>();
```

Am I using wrong types or should I just suppress these warnings?

Comment: For the records: The following line of code from your post won't compile, since java.util.List is an interface, not a class.      private List<String> phones =new List<String>();  You'll need to replace new List<String>() with new ArrayList<String>(), for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can usually suppress those warnings. The core Java API was never updated for Java 5 generics, and so all of the `Vector`s that come back from those methods are equivalent to `Vector<Object>` and there's no type-safe way to get it.

That said, the *safest* thing to do is to actually loop through the returned `List` and do something like `String.valueOf`, since they could hypothetically be `Double` or `DateTime` values in there. That's usually not a real threat in practice, but you could so something like this on Java 8, I think: `doc.getItemValue("phones").stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Additionally, if you use the OpenNTF Domino API, there's a `getItemValues(String name, Class<T> type)` that will do the necessary casting and conversion and return a true `List<String>` directly.